# Using a Content delivery network close to Egypt

Tags: optimization, hosting, cdn, cloud-hosting

I'm looking for a Content delivery network (CDN) geographically close to Egypt. For some reason the Amazon Cloud servers and some others like MaxCDN don't have locations in the African continent or Arabic side of the world. The first I can understand somehow, but why not in the Arabic countries?

Besides the CDN we want to use, we are using php X-cache, GZIP compression and optimize all images with Smush.It on the server side. (hosted in Europe)

What is the best solution for building a image intensive website, 99% used by internet users from Egypt?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.cdn-locator.com/cdns, @Jason? http://www.cdn-locator.com/cdn/country/egypt returned several results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get a host from there. there are couple of companies there. check these:

http://www.citynethost.com

http://link.net/english/default

I don't think any of them offer out-of-the-box CDN, buy you can talk to them.